# C++ inline ASM exception on return

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

Due to a WPO patch the way a function I called through an injected DLL changed.
The function is a __fastcall

The original function looked like

```
PUSH EAX
MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP]
PUSH EAX
LEA EBX,[ARG.22]
LEA EDI,[ARG.23]
CALL Function
```

So I could call it via:

```
Push ebx
Push edi
Push 0  
Push 0  
lea ebx,dword ptr ss:[ecx]
lea edi,dword ptr ss:[edx]
call Function
Pop edi
Pop ebx
retn
```

The function only needed 2 ascii strings.

Now after the WPO the function changed to

```
PUSH 0
LEA EDX,[LOCAL.22]
PUSH EDX
LEA EDX,[LOCAL.23] 
XOR ECX,ECX   
CALL Function
```

A common fastcall, which looks simpler. But the issue started that the ebp register carried a number while esi and edi the same strings but in Unicode.

While the call still needed only 2 arguments the registers contained additional which was required.

So instead of calling the function via 2 Ascii on ecx and edx I wrote a struct which contained the strings as ascii and unicode.

My attempt to solve it looked like

```
pushad
push 0
lea edi,dword ptr ss:[ecx+0x20]
lea esi,dword ptr ss:[ecx]
mov ebp, 100    

lea edx,dword ptr ss:[ecx+0x50]
push edx
lea edx,dword ptr ss:[ecx+0x40]
xor ecx, ecx
call Function
pop edx
popad
retn
```

I followed it in the debugger and the call is processed as it should be, but after the the function returns to my asmstub and returns to my c++ code my code creates an exception on write.

Did I make a fundamental asm mistake such as messing up the order which causes the exception?

Comment: Q: It sounds like you're writing a native Windows app or dll with MS Visual Studio, correct?  Q: What version of MSVS?  What exactly do you mean by "WPO Patch"?   Q: What is the exact message in your "exception on write"? SUGGESTION: Try compiling some test code using "/Fa" and examine the assembly output.

Comment: I made a simple asm mistake. EDX has already me poped from the stack within the called function to only one pop was missing.

Comment: Q: What was the exact error you got?  A good old "0xc000005: access violation"? Q: What did you mean by "WPO patch"?  Do you mean MSVS "Whole Program Optimization"?  If so, how did you think it was related?

Comment: You can post an answer to your question, and mark it "accepted".  This is preferable to editing your question to say "solved", since the StackOverflow system will still list the question as "unanswered" until it has an answer in the answer space.